# Arrangements of $n$ people with $2$ different conditions.

Tags: combinatorics

There are two conditions set by this question, which are:

i) Mr. and Mrs. Smith must sit next to each other.

For this, I just treat the Smiths as $1$ object with $2$ ways to order them. Then there are $2(n-1)!$ arrangements.

ii) Mrs. Tucker is $k$ positions away from the Smiths. So, there are (k-1) people between them.

This is what's confusing me a bit. I've tried breaking this into cases, but I've just confused myself. Do I need to consider $k$ being different sizes relative to $n$?

Answer (score 0):

For i, you are correct.  For ii, I assume you must have maybe some people Mrs Tucker, then k people, then the Smiths, then maybe some people.  Following your previous approach, you have $n-k-3$ places for the first of (Mrs Tucker and the Smiths), four orders for the three of them, and $n-3$ other people to order.